# PHP login only accept a static password

Tags: php

Please assist me I am a php beginner and I am trying to building a system that has a register page and a login page but now I am having issues with my login page, it only accepts a static password which is "password". I don't know why, what am I doing wrong? I have also added my registration script below the login script.

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("config.php");

$msg = "";

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

  $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $password = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

  if($email == "" || $password == "")
    $msg = "Email and Password are both required!";
  else{
    $sql = $conn->query ("SELECT user_id, password, is_active FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
    if($sql->num_rows > 0){
        $data = $sql->fetch_array();
        if('password' == $password){
          if($data['is_active'] == 0)
            $msg = "Please Verify Your Email!";
          else{
              $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
              $_SESSION['name'] = $f_name;

              header('Location: home.php');
              //$msg = "Your are logged in";
            }
      }else
          $msg = "Incorrect email and password combination";
      }
  }
}

 ?>
```

Create.php

```
<?php
include("config.php");

    // use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    // use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    //
    // include_once "PHPMailer\PHPMailer.php";
    // include_once "PHPMailer\Exception.php";
    // include 'PHPMailer\SMTP.php';


    global $error1, $error2, $error3, $error4, $error5, $error6, $msgSuccess;
    global $info, $fail;

    $user_name = $user_surname = $user_phone = $user_email = $user_password = "";
    //$date_time = date('Y/m/d');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $f_name = $_POST['f_name'];
      $surname = $_POST['surname'];
      $phone = $_POST['phone'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];


      $sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}'");
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql_query);

      if(!empty($f_name) && !empty($surname) && !empty($phone) && !empty($email) && !empty($password)){

        if($count > 0){
            $error1 ="<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
            <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' arial-label='close'>&times;</a>User with Email Already Exist.
            </div>'";
    } else{
      $user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $f_name);
      $user_surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $surname);
      $user_phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $phone);
      $user_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email);
      $user_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password);

      if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
          $error2 ="<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
          <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' arial-label='close'>&times;</a>Email is Invalid.
          </div>";

      }

      if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $user_name)){
          $error3 ="<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
          <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' arial-label='close'>&times;</a> Only Letter Allowed for Firstname.
          </div>";

      }

      if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $user_surname)){
          $error4 ="<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
          <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' arial-label='close'>&times;</a>Only Letter Allowed for Lastname.
          </div>";
      }

      if(!filter_var($user_phone, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)){
        $error5 ="<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
        <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' arial-label='close'>&times;</a>Only numbers Allowed for phone number.
        </div>";
      }

      if((preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $user_name)) && (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $user_surname))
      && (filter_var($user_phone, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT))
      && (filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))){

        $activation_key = md5(rand().time());
        $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (f_name, surname, phone, email, password,
          activation_key, is_active, date_time)
          VALUES('{$f_name}', '{$surname}', '{$phone}', '{$email}', '{$password}', '{$activation_key}', '0', now())";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        // $mail = new PHPMailer();
        //
        // $mail->isSMTP();
        // $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        // $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
        // $mail->Port=587;
        // $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
        // $mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
        // $mail->Username='****************';
        // $mail->Password='**************';
        //
        // $mail->setFrom('********@gmail.com');
        // $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);
        // $mail->Subject = "Please Verify Email!";
        // $mail->isHTML(true);
        // $mail->Body = "
        //               Please Click on the link below:<br/>
        //
        //               <a href='localhost/catch.a.ride/confirm.php?email=$email&activation_key=$activation_key'>Click Here</a>";
        //
        // if($mail->send())
        //     $msg = "You have been registerd, please verify your email!";
        // else
        //     $msg = "Failed to register! please try again later"; // .$mail->ErrorInfo;

      }

      }

  }else{
    if(empty($f_name)){
      $error3 ="<div class='alert alert-danger'>
      <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' arial-label='close'>&times;</a> First name field can not be empty.
      </div>";
    }elseif (empty($surname)){
      $error4 ="<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
      <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' arial-label='close'>&times;</a>Last name field can not be empty.
      </div>";
    }elseif (empty($phone)){
      $error5 ="<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
      <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' arial-label='close'>&times;</a> Phone number field can not be empty.
      </div>";
    }elseif (empty($email)){
      $error2 ="<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
      <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' arial-label='close'>&times;</a>Email field can not be empty.
      </div>";
    }elseif (empty($password)){
      $error6 ="<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
      <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' arial-label='close'>&times;</a>Password field can not be empty.
      </div>";
    }else {
      $msgSuccess = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
      <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' arial-label='close'>&times;</a> Added suucessfully, please follow the link xxxxx for activation.
      </div>";
    }
}

}
?>
```

Comment: `if('password' == $password){` well...

Comment: Also, if that was your actual password change it immediately everywhere you used it. The history of your edits is still visible.

Comment: Thanks.. changed my passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `$data = $sql->fetch_array();` data `$data` will be an array.

In the `if('password' == $password)` condition you should add 'password' as `$data['password']` like that.

Answer (score 1):

Should be `if(data['password'] == $password)`

Your getting the information from the database but checking it incorrectly. Also maybe look into using password hash to make these more safe. And the usual, bind your parameters. Hope this helps